# Keeping Cursor position at required position

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

How to maintain the cursor position at correct position when we insert an emoticon in between some text?
example: if my text is like, "hello world!!"
if I place cursor after hello's "o", then after emoticon, the cursor should be at the end of the emoticon entered.
Can anyone help me?
I have a message box named "textmessagebox" and events for emoticon icon click, textmessagebox lost focus,textmessagebox got focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  I have a textbox and a button which inserts :-) into the text at the correct postion when the button is clicked.

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           int SelectionStart = MyTextBox.SelectionStart + 3;
           MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text.Insert(MyTextBox.SelectionStart, ":-)");
           MyTextBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
           MyTextBox.SelectionStart = SelectionStart;
        }
```